# How to pass arguments to TCL source

Tags: arguments, tcl

In tcl, now I want to source a file with some arguments, for instance, source file arg1 arg2. I use a procedure like this

```
proc src {file args} {
  set argv $::argv
  set argc $::argc
  set ::argv $args
  set ::argc [llength $args]
  set code [catch {uplevel [list source $file]} return]
  set ::argv $argv
  set ::argc $argc
  return -code $code $return
}
```

If I do `src file arg1 arg2`, it works perfectly. However, I can only provide the `arg1` and `arg2` as one string, for instance: `set string "arg1 arg2"`. Then my `src` proc will take this string as one argument. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want *argument expansion*. Tcl has special syntax for that (from 8.5 onwards):

```
src $file {*}$string
```

See that `{*}`? If it's first in the word, the rest of the word is parsed (as a Tcl list) into multiple words which are used.

---

In 8.4 and before, you had to do this instead:

```
eval [linsert $string 0 src $file]
```

Or any number of other horrible recipes. People tended to be lazy and write:

```
eval src $file $string
```

But that would blow up if `$file` had spaces in, or `$string` was formatted as anything other than a canonical list, such as:

```
set string {
    arg1
    arg2
}
```

That's a legal list. Non-canonical though, and makes the `eval` blow up without precautions.

We added `{*}` in 8.5 precisely because we were fed up with all the subtle bugs from the `eval`s…